# Cannot Install Theme

Tags: installation

my problem is that I cannot install this specific theme and also I cannot install the required module for that. As you can see in the picture, I cannot check the checkbox to install it.
By the way I am using WAMP and Drupal 9.4.1
[image]

Comment: You should probably check with the IU web team about specifically what the IU Paragraphs module requires.

Comment: Clicking those down facing arrows should tell you the reasons those modules are not installable.

Answer (score 2):

When on the page for installing modules it's not possible to select a module, it means that at least one of the following conditions is true. (All these conditions are checked in [`ModulesListForm::buildRow()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Form%21ModulesListForm.php/function/ModulesListForm%3A%3AbuildRow/9.3.x).)

- The module isn't compatible with the installed Drupal release
- The module requires a PHP version that is higher than the PHP version used for the site
- One of the module dependencies is missing

In any case, the full module description shows also the reason why the module cannot be installed.
What the screenshot show is a short description. To see the full description, you need to click on those little arrows (which could not seem arrows) shown between the module name and the module short description.

> [image: screenshot]

Notice that the *2.0.x* branch of the *IU Paragraphs* module is rather specific about the Drupal version that requires, since its [.info.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/iu_paragraphs/-/blob/2.0.x/iu_paragraphs.info.yml) file contains the following line.

```yaml
core_version_requirement: ^9.1.0-alpha1
```

The 8.x-1.x branch is compatible only with Drupal 8 (and not all the Drupal 8 releases.) (See its [.info.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/iu_paragraphs/-/blob/8.x-1.x/iu_paragraphs.info.yml) file.)

Both the *2.0.x* and the *8.x-1.x* branches require some contributed modules. For example, the dependencies for the *2.0.x* branch are the following.

- autocomplete_deluxe:autocomplete_deluxe
- dropzonejs:dropzonejs_eb_widget
- drupal:block
- drupal:field
- drupal:field_layout
- drupal:file
- drupal:image
- drupal:layout_discovery
- drupal:link
- drupal:media
- drupal:node
- drupal:options
- drupal:path
- drupal:taxonomy
- drupal:text
- drupal:user
- drupal:views
- embed:embed
- entity_browser:entity_browser
- entity_embed:entity_embed
- entity_reference_revisions:entity_reference_revisions
- field_group:field_group
- file_entity:file_entity
- media_entity_browser:media_entity_browser
- paragraphs:paragraphs
- svg_image_field:svg_image_field
- viewsreference:viewsreference

Leaving out the lines starting with *drupal:*, which list Drupal core modules, the other lines list contributed modules that needs to be installed in order to install the *IU Paragraphs* module.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
https://ibb.co/yfwfY8D
These are the errors and missing things.

Comment: There are missing modules, which are ones followed by *(missing)* and there are modules that are present, but not installed, the ones followed by *(disabled)*.